# Why does my model have a .blend?

Tags: modeling, file-format

Whenever I download a model on DeviantArt I get a .blend in my model, what is that?

Comment: .blend is a Blender's native format, so putting it along with model's OBJ/FBX/ABC, etc means that you get source files. For example source models usually comes without triangulation or applied modifers. Which makes things much simplier if you want to edit it somehow.